# Arduino write on standard firmata, using c# SerialPort.Write()

Tags: c#, arduino, arduino-ide

so, I'm super new to using an arduino, and I can't seem to understand what happens when I do SerialPort.Write() to one.  like, what function within the standard firmata occurs?

Comment: Could you elaborate your question? I don't really understand what you mean. You mean when your C# program writes serial data to an arduino, and you wanna know what happens in the arduino? Is that it?

Comment: yeah, like I can do SerialPort.Write(byteArray, int, int);  in my C# program, but I can't figure out what the arduino does.  like, where that byteArray gets sent within the arduino firmata code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the computer sends data to the arduino trough a serial port, the arduino receives that data and stores it in a buffer until your arduino code does a `Serial.read()` (or any other variant used to read the serial data). Once the data is read, the buffer is cleared.

It's worth noting, however, that the handling of the usb comunication is NOT done by the arduino's main chip (the one in which your code runs), but rather in a separate chip installed on the arduino board solely for this purpose. The arduino library's Serial class handles the communication between the main chip and the one that handles the usb comms.